# MySQL - Full Text Search - Losing index

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, full-text-search

So here is the scenario:

- MySQL
- have 1 MYISAM Table
- colum named v.value has a full text index

Basic query works fine, uses the index as expected:

```
SELECT p.online_identifier
FROM (...)
WHERE  r.area_id = 3 AND s.state_id= 4
AND (snap.area_has_catalogues_attributes_id = 7028
AND MATCH (v.value) AGAINST('+SomeBrand' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

---

Now when I add an OR, the full text search index (on v.value) is not used.
I run Explain to verify it.

The query would look something like this:

`(...)
WHERE  r.area_id = 3 AND s.state_id= 4 AND 
        (snap.area_has_catalogues_attributes_id = 7028 AND MATCH (v.value) AGAINST('+SomeBrand' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
OR (snap.area_has_catalogues_attributes_id = 7045 AND MATCH (v.value) AGAINST('+OtherBrand' IN BOOLEAN MODE))`

---

I dont understand why.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something interesting: The query you have is actually causing the FULLTEXT indexing to be ignored. Don't worry, it is not your fault. I wrote about this before : [Is there a way to hint to query optimizer to MySQL which constraints should be done first?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22130/877)

After looking over my answer and its subsequent links, now let's look at your original query:

```
SELECT p.online_identifier
FROM (...)
WHERE  r.area_id = 3 AND s.state_id= 4
AND (snap.area_has_catalogues_attributes_id = 7028
AND MATCH (v.value) AGAINST('+SomeBrand' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

You will have to execute the FULLTEXT search alone and retrieve IDs only.

Use those IDs to join to the other table aliases.

---

Let me take a query from one of [my other links](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7216/877) to demonstrate what to do to your query

Instead of this query

```
select * from seeds WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST
("mount cameroon" IN BOOLEAN MODE) = 4;
```

you must refactor it into something like this:

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(
    SELECT id,MATCH(text) AGAINST
    ("mount cameroon" IN BOOLEAN MODE) score
    FROM seeds
    WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST
    ("mount cameroon" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) A
INNER JOIN seeds B USING (id)
WHERE A.score = 4;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: First of all, big thanks for the great help.
It guided to me to the right direction :)

I tried your tip and MySQL did use the index :) Resulting in less rows processed.

Comment: If you dont mind can I have your input about the following question?
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689714/mysql-analyze-query].

It´s about the performance of the query that resulted from this :)